# Is there a way to make Firefox use cache when the back button is pressed?

Tags: http, firefox

When I use the back button in Chrome and IE (and the page that is being requested was fetched via HTTP GET) I have noticed that the page is retrieved from a local cache. i.e. no new HTTP request is made.

Firefox works differently and makes a new HTTP request when the back button is pressed.

Is there a way to make firefox behave like Chrome and IE?

Comment: Maybe a better fit for superuser.com

Comment: Firefox will use the cache in this case if the page is cached.  It's hard to say anything else (like why the page is not being cached) without a link to the page.

Comment: I guess my question then is how to make firefox cache the page, I have tried with the HTTP header: Cache-Control: max-age=3600000 but for me this makes no difference, a page fetched via a GET will still be reloaded, when the back button is pressed